# windows system command redirection in c

Tags: c

I can get the redirection to work from the command line but I cannot get the redirection to work from my C code. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

// This works:   -hashfile command completed successfully.

```
memset(&tchar[0], 0, sizeof(tchar));
sprintf(tchar, "certutil -hashfile \"\%s\"\ MD5", output_file);  
system(tchar);
```

This doesn't --> Error:  Expected no more than 2 args, received 4

```
sprintf(tchar, "certutil -hashfile \"\%s\"\ MD5 ^> "\C:\\TEMP\\image.cksm\"\"", output_file);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are problems with `sprintf`'s *format* argument which is invalid:

- **Compile error**: the dblquote(*"*) from ***"**\C:\...* is ending the format string, making the rest of it (path) illegal.
- **Runtime error**: the caret(*^*) from ***^**>* makes the following redirecting operator (*>*) to be treated as a literal (as a consequence as a program argument; same thing with the following filename), so *certutil* receives 4 arguments instead of (the expected) 2. You only need to escape special chars if you want to treat them as literals, and discard their special meaning.
- Some over (*C*) escaping: the 2nd and 4th backslashes(*\*) from *\"**\**%s\"**\*** - not critical, but over-complicates the string.

To make it work, change the code to:

```
sprintf(tchar, "certutil -hashfile \"%s\" MD5 > \"C:\\TEMP\\image.cksm\"", output_file);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it still has the same error:   Expected no more than 2 args, received 4

Comment: That's odd... What's the _Win_ version, and what compiler do you use? I successfully compiled it using _VStudio21k0_ and ran it on _Win10_.

Comment: Windows 7 with a National Instruments LabWindows CVI compiler.

Comment: I successfully ran my executable on _W2k8R2_ and _W2k3_ (well, on _W2k3_ it failed but only because the older _certutil_ doesn't know about the hash algorithm argument, anyway after removing it everything was OK). So, I guess there's a difference between [`system`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/277bwbdz(v=vs.100).aspx) implementations of _VStudio_ and _LabWindows_. I'll try to download a free version of the _CVI_ compiler and the additional libs (_libc_ / _msvcr_) available for download. But first: does `certutil -hashfile "%FILE%" MD5 > "c:\temp\image.cksm"` run OK from _cmd_?

Comment: Yes, certutil -hashfile "c:\temp\myfile.img" MD5 > "c:\temp\image.cksm"  works from cmd. (sorry for the delay).

Comment: FYI This works by executing cmd.exe from a command script:   sprintf(tchar, "cmd.exe /c C:\\temp\\create_temp_md5.cmd\ %s\n", filename); 
system(tchar);

AND IN THE CMD FILE:
certutil -hashfile %1 MD5 > C:\\temp\\image_checksum.md5

Comment: I wasn't able to find a free (non trial) version of the _CVI_ compiler. I suppose that `output_file` itself doesn't have any doublequotes. What does `printf("%s\n", tchar);` output for the command that passed to `system` keeps failing? For me it shows: _certutil -hashfile "C:\SomeDir\SomeFile.txt" MD5 > "C:\TEMP\image.cksm"_.